# from playsound import playsound playsound('C:\\Users\\Home\\Desktop\\DESKTOP\\Python\\play.mp3')

Tags: python

PS C:\Users\Home\Desktop\DESKTOP\Python> & C:/Users/Home/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe c:/Users/Home/Desktop/DESKTOP/Python/01_hello.py      Error 261 for command:         open "C:\Users\Home\Desktop\DESKTOP\Python\play.mp3"     The driver cannot recognize the specified command.

Answer (score 0):

Try to elaborate your question everytime you post. I think its the version issue you should install playsound version 1.2.2

```
pip install playsound==1.2.2
```